# Getting the name of a class from within a class definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So I have my base class:

```
class Foo():
    pass
```

I'm never going to instantiate this class - I just want it as a custom namespace.  One of the things I want from it is its name:

```
>>> Foo.__name__
'Foo'
```

But I want to change the interface to this, so that there's no underscores.  Getting the name of the class from the class object is going to happen a lot, so it should be cleaner:

```
class Foo:
    def name():
        return Foo.__name__
```

This works great!  Oh, except I have the name "Foo" hard coded.  I might as well just have it return a string.  That's not good enough, because I need to inherit this adjustment:

```
class Bar(Foo):
   pass

>>> Bar.name()
'Foo'
```

No bueno.

Basically, I need a class function that returns the name of the class, and which will still work when inherited.  I can't use self because I'm not making instances.  Is there anything which will achieve a similar result?  Do functions know about the namespace they are called from?  If I really need to use objects I will, but for my purposes that will be uglier than a simple class hierarchy.

EDIT:  I do not not believe this question is the same as the one it has been linked with.  The solutions provided to the other question - mainly invoking the .__class__ attribute - would not work as an answer to this question because in my example I explicitly avoid instantiating objects.  Also, the best answer provided here (using the @classmethod decorator to get the class object as a "self"-esque arg) appears nowhere in the linked alternative.  Also, I believe my question to be framed in a clearer and more basic way than its purported duplicate.  The same goes for the answer chosen.

Comment: Read up on `@classmethod`

Comment: Your example errors for me, because it expects a `self` argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it a class method with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and return the name of the class that's passed in:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def name(cls):
        return cls.__name__

class Bar(Foo): pass
```

This returns the correct name in each case:

```
>>> Foo.name()
'Foo'
>>> Bar.name()
'Bar'
```

Comment: Reading about decorators now, thanks for the lead.  Looks awesome.